# JQuery not processing ColdFusion JSON

Tags: jquery, json, coldfusion

I have a simple cfc that queries a database and returns a JSON object

```
<cfcomponent>
<cfsetting showdebugoutput="false" enablecfoutputonly="true">
<cffunction name="getNew" access="remote" returntype="query" returnFormat="json" secureJSON="false">
    <cfquery datasource="#request.datasource#" name="qSelectNotes">
        SELECT TOP 3 university_ID, name FROM university
    </cfquery>
    <cfreturn qSelectNotes>
</cffunction>
```

The CFC is returning the following JSON as viewed in FireBug:

```
   {"COLUMNS":["UNIVERSITY_ID","NAME"],"DATA":[[1,"MIT"],[2,"EMORY"],[3,"UNC"]]}
```

My jQuery function continually returns the error

```
   "SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character".
```

My function is below:

```
    $.ajax({
       url: "notes_DB_check.cfc?method=getNew",
       dataType: "json", 
       success: function (myData) {
       alert(myData.DATA[1][1]); 
           },
        error: function (request, status, error) {
           alert("REQUEST:\t" + request + "\nSTATUS:\t" + status + "\nERROR:\t" + error);
           }
      });
```

Comment: There's really no such thing as "ColdFusion JSON", there's just "JSON". The JSON you post there is completely valid (I'm sure you checked that), so whatever *is* making your jquery code choke isn't *that* JSON.

Comment: This was a helpful comment.  I've been so locked into this that I didn't think it might be something else interfering.  I had another jQuery function on the page that was interfering with this one.  Once I removed the function this one worked like a charm!  Thanks!!!

Comment: Cool! :-) You should summarise that as an answer and mark the question answered. It'll save people time trying to help if they don't read these comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Adam Cameron for pointing me in the right direction.  The component and the JSON were valid and it turns out there was another jQuery function on the page that was interfering with this function.

Answer (score 2):

Try setting output="false" as an attribute in your cfcomponent and cffunction tags.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one into your js

```
 $.ajax({
   url: "notes_DB_check.cfc?method=getNew",

   success: function (myData) {
   var abc = JSON.parse(myData);
   alert(abc);// Here you will run a for loop and then populate values from json 
       },
    error: function (request, status, error) {
       alert("REQUEST:\t" + request + "\nSTATUS:\t" + status + "\nERROR:\t" + error);
       }
  });
```